# CSS Framework javascript issue

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I am currently utilising the beauter framework to develop a website.

The framework has a nav bar function that allows a hamburger icon to be used when the screen is to small to see all navigation links horizontally. However I cannot get to work and " javascript:void(0)" appears when I click the icon without any of links being showed in the way the online demo works.

http://beauter.outboxcraft.com/docs/navigation/

Please see snippets of my code below

```
 <script
  src="https://rawgit.com/outboxcraft/beauter/master/beauter.min.js">
  </script>


  <li style="float:right;"><a href="#" > </a></li>
   <li class="-icon">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="topnav('myTopnav2')">☰</a>
   </li>
```

Any indication of what I'm doing wrong or how I could improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the javascript console? What's the expected result of running that code and clicking the button?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (They can include external JavaScript and CSS resources, such as from the download page of the framework you're using. It doesn't, sadly, appear to be on cdnjs.com.)

Comment: VIewing the demo in the link should show what the icon is meant to do. Basically allow the user to view all navbar links when the screen it to small to show them in line